# Will I Be Significantly Limited as an iOS Developer with this Setup?

Tags: ios

I've been developing on Android for some time and would like to make the step into the iOS world. I've got my eye on a used MacBook (osx 10.6 snow leopard) and a used iPhone 3g (which won't have a SIM card). Does anyone know if I would be significantly limited as an iOS developer if I were to buy these older/used Mac products for development purposes?

Comment: This doesn't sound like a code problem...

Comment: Have you looked at the market penetration for the individual iPhones?  I'd start there, that will give you the best indication of which device to start with (Without looking, I'd have to say "yes" to your question, the 3G is an "old" phone).  As for the laptop, can't help there, I'm a Windows guy :)

Comment: apple often makes updates only available for the latest release of OS(X) and then requests App-updates to be made with the latest release of SDK. With a used device you might have problems in performance then soon. A 3G is way too old to make up-to-date development. Apple basically requests you to pay for hardware if you want to develop. But as mentioned by Putz1103 it is off-topic here.

Comment: Close voters: this question is *not* primarily opinion based. It has an objectively correct answer.

Comment: @Putz1103 - Well, this *does* seem on-topic, as this question [generally covers "software tools commonly used by programmers"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), especially given others' comments here about outdated hardware and the new App Store publishing guidelines.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on your ambitions. I will mention these issues:

- Apple requires all new submitted apps to be built with XCode 5 and iOS7. That does not run on Snow Leopard. Check to see if the Macbook model you are buying can be upgraded to Mavericks.
- You won't be able to test different screen sizes and retina/non-retina with just the iPhone 3G.
- The 3G is SLOW compared to newer iPhones, so there will be some difference there when testing. This could be an issue if you are developing a game or other resource intensive stuff - but it can also be issues as simple as a crash not appearing on your phone, but it does on a 5S, because timing.

You can learn a lot with the simulator, but you will find some problems needs to be debugged on an actual device.

I'd say: You can certainly get your app into the AppStore with the proposed setup, just make sure the computer you are buying can be upgraded to Mavericks, or it will be a no go. If you are serious about developing for Apple, you will soon find yourself in need of better tools (but these will be enough for getting you started).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you'll be very limited. In fact, you won't be able to use it to actually publish on the App Store starting February 1st. Increase your budget a little bit and get a Mac that supports Mavericks, and get a cheap iPod touch, iPhone 4, or iPad 2.

Answer (score 1):

> Does anyone know if I would be significantly limited as an iOS developer if I were to buy these older/used Mac products for development purposes?

**Yes.** You won't be able to run the latest version of iOS on an iPhone 3G, and you won't be able to run the latest version of Xcode on OS X 10.6. That means you'll be developing on an outdated platform, which doesn't make a lot of sense. It also means that you won't be able to submit apps to the iTunes App Store, as all new apps have to run on iOS 7.

Also, the iPhone 3G sports a 3.5" non-retina screen, whereas all current iPhone and iPod Touch hardware has a 4" retina display. This fact alone is enough reason to reject the nearly 6-year-old 3G.